# Como corrigir problemas de encoding em uma página de aplicação web?

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, jboss, wildfly

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação JAVA com o framework Spring v3.1.0, porém, ao tentar acessar uma página apresenta erro de *encoding*:

> EvoluÃ§Ã£o

Como resolver esse problema? Encontrei diversos caminhos, mas nenhum funcionou:

```xml
<servlet-container name="default" use-listener-encoding="true" default-encoding="UTF-8">
     <jsp-config/>
     <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
```

Mas não funcionou, tentei também colocar o filtro no arquivo web.xml:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
         org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Coloquei no cabeçalho também o tipo de *encoding*, e também não funcionou:

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8;" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

E evidente, também tentei passar tal informação via HTML:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

O arquivo JSP também está em UTF-8 e o navegador também.

Alguém tem uma solução para esse problema? Essa é a minha primeira aplicação nessa tecnologia, estou apanhando um pouco com essas coisas.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: E quanto ao `iso-8859-1`?

Comment: Dá problema do mesmo jeito, porém, o UTF-8 é o padrão em todos os níveis: banco de dados, JSP, JS, CSS, etc...

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5933805/4056678).

Comment: Isso ai @renan, sua dica ajudou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @EwertonMelo posta como resposta a solução que encontrou, explica como fez para resolver. Sua resposta pode ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema.